# Nginx - How do I proxy all 404 requests to a different server

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

I'm trying to proxy all my 404 requests to a fallback server, also for 404s returned by php script of host server.

```
recursive_error_pages off;
error_page 404 = @missing;

location @missing {
    proxy_pass http://anotherserver;
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;
}

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

So whenever php application returns 404 it's gracefully falling back to anotherserver, but the problem is it's not able to pass URIs since it's inside a named block.

How do I configure nginx to proxy to **anotherserver** only when host server's application returns 404 ?

Comment: Have you tried [nginx upstream](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html). **PS :** I believe this is a question more appropriate for superuser or serverfault

Answer (score 1):

You can pass another server in location block using [nginx upstream](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html):

```
recursive_error_pages off;
error_page 404 = @missing;

upstream anotherserver404 {
    server anotherserver.only404.com:80;
}

location @missing {
    proxy_pass http://anotherserver404;
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;
}

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```